# how can i change TextField hover border effect in material-ui?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui, css-selectors

so in persian language the direction is `rtl` .

i wanna know how can i change this input to my language for the project ?

Please take a look at this Image

[image]

this is what i wanna do but i have no idea how can i change the border line on hover.
I can change the label text with `position: relative or absolute` and move it, but when we click the input to type, idk what to do with that borderline?

how can i move that ? I Will appreciate some help.

[image]

material ui code

```
import * as React from "react";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";

      <div style={{ margin: "10rem 5rem" }}>
        <TextField
          id="outlined-basic"
          label="متن"
          variant="outlined"
        />
      </div>
```

Comment: Take a look into this MUI [docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/right-to-left/). They also have a [code sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/54znnm?file=/demo.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the inner fieldset text-align to "right" instead of "left", and also change the transform X property of label, also you can change from left:0 to right:0, to move the placement of label from left to right, there are multiple solutions, just check documentation to learn how to change properties of inner elements.

Comment: You're a lifesaver. thank you so much